# Proving a function to be exponential given that it satisfies certain equations.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, elliptic-functions

I am trying to do all the exercises from Tom M. Apostol's *Dirichlet series and Modular functions in number theory* and I could not think about the following problem from the chapter "Elliptic functions".

> Problem - Let $\omega_1$ and  $\omega_2$ be complex numbers with non real ratio. Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and assume there are constants $a$ and $b$ such that $f(z+\omega_1) = a f(z)$  , $f(z+ \omega_2) = b f(z)$ , for all $z$. Prove that $f(z) = A\exp(Bz)$, where $\exp(x) = e^x$ and $A$, $B$ are constants.

I tried a solution by putting $z= 0$ and seeing what happens for  $\omega_1$ , $\omega_2$ but I couldn't prove any relation that could imply that $f$ must be an exponential function.

Can somebody please give hints.

Comment: Just a guess: assume $f$ has the given form, and try to figure out $a,b,\omega_1,\omega_2$.  If you succeed, then do it backwards.  For example, if $f(z)=e^z$ we can take $a=1, \omega_1=2\pi i, b= e, \omega_2=1$.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4183695/42969

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the ratio $f/(A \exp(Bz))$ with $A$ and $B$ chosen such that $A \exp(Bz)$ has the same quasiperiods as $f$, i.e. the ratio is elliptic. Remember Liouville's theorem

Comment: Apostol  never mentioned quasiperiods in the book. Can you please explain what they are? I googled it but couldn't find it.

Comment: I mean the $a$ and $b$ you defined.