# Holomorphic function such that $\theta\left(z+\omega_j\right)=a_j\theta\left(z\right)$ satisfies $\theta\left(z\right)=ae^{bz}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions, meromorphic-functions

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $\mathbb{Z}\omega_1+\mathbb{Z}\omega_2$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\theta$ be an entire function such that there exist $a_1,a_2\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\theta\left(z+\omega_j\right)=a_j\theta\left(z\right)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $j\in\left\{1,2\right\}$. Prove that $\theta\left(z\right)=ae^{bz}$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$.

So, if $\theta=0$, there is nothing to prove. Assume $\theta\neq 0$. Observe that $a_1\neq0\neq a_2$ because $\theta\left(z\right)=a_j\theta\left(z-\omega_j\right)$ and $\theta\neq 0$.

If $a_1=a_2=1$ then $\theta$ is an entire elliptic function and therefore it is constant, and this proves what we want (take $b=0$). Assume that at least one $a_j$ is not equal to $1$. It follows that $\theta\neq 0$ cannot be constant, since otherwise $a_1=a_2=1$.

Since $\theta'$ satisfies the same conditions as $\theta$ does, assume we could prove what we want for $\theta'$. If $\theta'=ae^{bz}$, we cannot have $b\neq 0$ since otherwise $\theta=az+c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{C}$, which shows that $a\neq 0$ (because $\theta$ is not constant) and then, using the hypothesis on $\theta$ and comparing coefficients, we would obtain $a=a_ja$, which implies $a_1=a_2=1$, a contradiction. So $\theta'=ae^{bz}$ where $b\neq 0$ (and $a\neq 0$ because $\theta$ is not constant), and therefore $\theta=\frac{1}{b}\theta'+d$ for some $d\in\mathbb{C}$. Using that both $\theta$ and $\theta'$ satisfy the conditions of the statement, one easily obtains $d=a_jd$, so $d=0$ because at least one $a_j$ is not equal to $1$. So $\theta=\frac{1}{b}ae^{bz}$ also has the desired form.

The above paragraph shows that if we prove the problem for $\theta'$ then it is also solved for $\theta$ (assuming that $\theta\neq 0$ and at least one $a_j$ is not equal to $1$). I do not know whether it helps.

Another idea I had was the following: keep assuming $\theta\neq 0$ and at least one $a_j$ is not equal to $1$ (the other cases were already handled) and consider the meromorphic function $\psi=\frac{\theta'}{\theta}$. Since both $\theta$ and $\theta'$ satisfy the conditions of the statement and $a_1\neq 0\neq a_2$ (because $\theta\neq 0$), one easily shows that $\psi$ is an elliptic function. So if we could show that it is entire, we would be done: it would be constant and that would give what we want. But of course, $\psi$ may not be holomorphic: $\theta$ may have some zeros. I thought of using the above paragraph and take enough derivatives of $\theta$ to get rid of the possible zeros, but of course it does not work because taking derivatives may introduce new zeros.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: One very simple trick: construct a nice enough exponential function, say $g$ (obviously you need its parameters related to $a_1$ and $a_2$), and consider the quotient $\theta/g$. Show that it is entire and doubly periodic. Apply Liouville's theorem.

Comment: @justadzr: That's what I thought as well, and voted to close as a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1074745/42969, where this approach is suggested in the answers. However, on second thought, both answers at the older thread are not clear to me (I have left comments over there). That's why I reopened the question (and answered it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose $b \in \Bbb C$ such that $e^{\omega_1 b} = a_1$ and define $g(z) = e^{-bz} \theta(z)$. Then
$$
 g(z+\omega_1) = e^{-b(z+\omega_1)} a_1 \theta(z) = g(z) \, ,
$$
i.e. $g$ is $\omega_1$-periodic. It follows that
$$
 g(z) = h\left( e^{2\pi i z/\omega_1}\right)
$$
where $h$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C\setminus \{ 0 \}$. $h$ can be developed into a Laurent series
$$
 h(w) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n w^n \, .
$$

Now we use that $\theta(z+\omega_2) = a_2 \theta(z)$, so that
$$
 g(z+\omega_2) = e^{-b(z+\omega_2)} a_2 \theta(z) = B g(z) 
$$
with $B= e^{-b\omega_2}a_2$. It follows that
$$
 h(e^{2\pi i \omega_2/\omega_1} w) = B h(w)
$$
for all $w \ne 0$. Substituting this into the Laurent series of $h$ implies that
$$
 c_n \left( e^{2\pi i n\omega_2/\omega_1} - B\right) = 0
$$
for all $n$. The absolute value of $e^{2\pi i n\omega_2/\omega_1}$ is not one because $\omega_2/\omega_1$ is not a real number. It follows that $ e^{2\pi i n\omega_2/\omega_1} - B=0$ can hold only for at most one index $n$. So we have
$$
 h(w) = c_m w^m
$$
for some $m \in \Bbb Z$, so that
$$
 g(z) = c_m e^{2\pi i m z/\omega_1}
$$
and
$$
 \theta(z) = c_m e^{bz }e^{2\pi i m z/\omega_1}
$$
has the desired form.